# How to iterate through an ArrayList and only pull out 1 field from each object

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, iterator, jlist

I am working on a JList issue. I have an Array List of Objects the have 3 fields each. I want to put the lastName, firstName in the JList but can only figure out how to pull the last objects information out of the ArrayList.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

public class TestingListsGUI
{

private JFrame  frame;
String[]        values;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                TestingListsGUI window = new TestingListsGUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public TestingListsGUI()
{
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    // Create Array list and populate it with generic info for testing
    final List<JListsTesting> myList = new ArrayList<JListsTesting>();

    myList.add(new JListsTesting("Bruce", "James", "Totally Awesome"));
    myList.add(new JListsTesting("Potter", "Harry", "A Magician"));
    myList.add(new JListsTesting("Sanders", "Col", "The Chicken Meister"));
    myList.add(new JListsTesting("Bond", "James", "Licensed to Kill"));

    values = new String[myList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
    {

        values[i] = JListsTesting.getFirstName();

    }

    JList list = new JList();
    list.setModel(new AbstractListModel()
    {

        public int getSize()
        {
            return values.length;
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int index)
        {
            return values[index];
        }
    });

    list.setSelectedIndex(0);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setBounds(33, 23, 236, 249);
    frame.getContentPane().add(list);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `null` `LayoutManager`. Read next [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).
2. For filling values use next code:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
       values[i] = myList.get(i).getFirstName();
   }
   ```
3. You need't custom Model for `JList` just create `JList` with values constructor:

   `JList<String> list = new JList<String>(values);`

Also read [`JList` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)